# Emailing script - reply to message Gmail conversation

Tags: python, email, gmail, sendgrid

I have setup an email for my domain to forward emails to a my personal email. I'm writing a simple mailing script to reply to some emails i receive as forwarded email using the domain's email id. I'm using Sendgrid to do that. Whenever i send a response back though, it appears as a new conversation in Gmail inbox. I'm not sure what all params I need to set to make the conversation appear as a single bundle.

here's my sendgrid code:

```
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to(email)
message.set_from(my_name + " <" + my_email + ">")
message.set_subject(subject)
message.set_html(body.replace('\n', '<br />'))
message.set_text(body)
status, msg = sg.send(message)
```

I use the subject as: "Re: " +  
and use body from old conversation as:

```
On Fri, Aug 28, 2015 at 1:00 PM, senders_name <sender's email> wrote:
> 
> ...
```

Comment: You need to set the [In-Reply-To](http://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html) email header

Comment: In my case I was missing the subject in my reply and I added it following the format you mentioned to make it works Thanks @Ankit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @FSQ suggestion.I was able to make the email conversation attach together. I look up the Message Id from:
Gmail message > right side dropdown > show original

You should see something like:

```
In-Reply-To: <14f75e5a9b1.3f4.b2d01d@ismtpd-057>
Message-ID: <14f760957fc.5888.11ab5eb@ismtpd-085>
```

This is your message id. Send this in the header of email as:

```
message.set_headers({'In-Reply-To': '<14f760957fc.5888.11ab5eb@ismtpd-085>'})
```

And it works!

Comment: In my case adding headers as self.personalizations[0].add_header(Header("in_reply_to",'<14f760957fc.5888.11ab5eb@ismtpd-085>')).